# SQL, foreign keys in same table

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

Can I have a column in a table be a foreign key for another column in the table? For example, if one column is `OrderId` and another column is `RelatedOrderId`, could `OrderId` be a "foreign key" for `RelatedOrderId`? The idea behind such a relationship would be that it would tell whoever is looking at the table that those two columns can have overlapping values.

Comment: Yes, you can.  Tables do sometimes refer to themselves.

Answer (score 2):

This may be as close as you can get:

```
CREATE TABLE `a9` (
  `orderId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `relatedOrderId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`orderId`),
  KEY `abcd3` (`relatedOrderId`),
  CONSTRAINT `abcd3` FOREIGN KEY (`relatedOrderId`) REFERENCES `a9` (`orderId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

insert a9(orderId,relatedOrderId) values (1,null); -- success
insert a9(orderId,relatedOrderId) values (2,3); -- Error 1452
insert a9(orderId,relatedOrderId) values (2,1); -- success
```

And the referential integrity is not terribly strong with a `NULL` in the column `relatedOrderId`. But at least it suggests that if not `NULL` then it is valid.

To achieve a **circular** reference, one would need to do the below which seems fishy.

```
insert a9(orderId,relatedOrderId) values (1,null); -- success
insert a9(orderId,relatedOrderId) values (2,1); -- success
update a9 set relatedOrderId=2 where orderId=1; -- success

select * from a9;
+---------+----------------+
| orderId | relatedOrderId |
+---------+----------------+
|       2 |              1 |
|       1 |              2 |
+---------+----------------+
```

Forgive the datatypes chosen. It is only an example.